# How can I know where a Perl module is installed?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to know where the **IO::Socket::SSL** module, or more specifically, where the file **SSL.pm** is located. I already know that I have installed **IO::Socket::SSL** because `use IO::Socket::SSL` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use something like this:

```
%> perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'print $INC{"IO/Socket/SSL.pm"}';
```

and you get the path or an error if the module it is not installed in a proper path where perl can get it.

If you want to see if that module was installed:

```
%> perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 1
```

if you don't get any error, it's installed.

Sometimes it's important to see the version number of the installed package:

```
%> perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'print $IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION';
```

Or, if you are working on Windows, you have to use double-quotes:

```
C:\> perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e "print $IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION";
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
perldoc -l 'IO::Socket::SSL'
```

or alternatively in cmd.exe

```
perldoc -l "IO::Socket::SSL"
```

`-l` switch means "Display the module's file name". I find that it shows the fully qualified path to a module or (if applicable) to the module's external POD which is in the same directory as the module itself.

Comment: @Drt, I tested it in bash and it works with or without quotes. Are you using cmd.exe?

Comment: @Drt, You'd use double quotes with `cmd` (the Windows shell)

Comment: @ikegami, ok. I've updated the post to explicitly specify external POD.

Comment: I don't know why you'd need quotes in any shell...I see no metacharacters.

Comment: @runrig, it's a stylistic preference thing. Like how I always quote the expression for `awk`, `sed`, and `grep` even if they don't contain metacharacters.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

`perl -E'use IO::Socket::SSL; say $INC{"IO/Socket/SSL.pm"};'`

But a rule of thumb it most modules are typically in /usr/share/perl5 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The [pmtools package](https://metacpan.org/release/pmtools) provides an assortment of useful command line utils for finding where a package is installed (`pmpath`), what version it is at (`pmvers`), etc

Comment: This is surely the best answer. :)